# смена iframe по клику

Tags: html, iframe

есть 7 кнопок и 1 iframe, кликая по каждой должен меняться src в iframe

iframe представляет собой html страницу. 7 разных страниц.

Comment: Тег `<a target` **target** - почитать справку, можно на http://w3schools.com

Comment: это как отправить в гугл. можно ссылочку? или пример или хоть что нибуть